# angular 2 md-sidenav display list items on click in the dashboard

Tags: html, node.js, angular, angular2-routing

I have created a sidebar nav menu in angular 2 something like shown in the pic below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFvJQ.jpg

**UPDATE:**

But when i click on the link in the category list, i get all the products relevant to clicked category. But it is not displaying to the right in the dashboard.

My logic to display the products is in another component: **dashboard.component.html**

```
<div id="products" class="row list-group">
     ...
</div>
```

But on click of an item in sidebar (from sidebar component), i m not sure where to put the above div, so i get all the products filtered based on the click to my dashboard area.

Basically when i onclick getProducts (from one component: sidebar, the function from another component : dashboard should be called)

**sidenav.component.html**

```
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="example-sidenav" [ngStyle]="{ 'width.em': sidenavWidth }" opened="true" (mouseover)="increase()"
(mouseleave)="decrease()">
    <md-nav-list>
      <md-list-item routerLinkActive="active">
        <md-icon md-list-icon>room_service</md-icon>
        <div fxFlex="10"></div>
        <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
          <p class="lead">Smiles 4 abc </p>
              <div class="catList" id="catList">
              <a *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index" href="javascript:; " class="list-group-item " (click)="getProducts(cat._id,i)">{{cat.category_name}}</a>
              </div>
        </div>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>
  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

**sidenav.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.qty[1]=1;
this.catService.getMaincategories('Yes').subscribe(
       (mainCategories) => {

      this.categories = mainCategories.mainCategories
      let firstCatId = this.categories[0]._id;
      this.getProducts(firstCatId,0)
      }
      );

    this.navbar.ngOnInit();
 }

getProducts(category_id, i) { 
console.log('prod clicked..');
this.productService.getProductsOncategory(category_id).subscribe(
  (products) => {
    this.products = products.products
      }
    );
  }
```

**product.service.ts**

```
getProductsOncategory(category_id){
  let catUrl=this.domain+"products/getProductsOncategory"
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  let catIdObj = JSON.stringify({category_id:category_id,product_status:'Yes'})   
  return this.http.post(catUrl,catIdObj,{headers:headers})
  .map((response:Response)=>response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<sidenav></sidenav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic is very simple in Angular for dealing these type of problem. Follow following steps:

1. Create a Subject in your service:

   public products$ = Subject<{}>(); // use model instead of {}
2. In your sidenav component inject service and emit product data.

   this.service.products$.next(data)
3. In your dashboard component subscribe to subject.

   this.service.products$.subscribe(data => { console.log(data)});

Hope it will help.